# ¿Cómo mantener la sesion de un servidor cuando escriben en un textarea? JSF GlassFish

Tags: java, jsf, glassfish

Trabajo para una empresa donde desarrollamos una aplicación web, en ésta entre varias cosas le permitimos a los usuarios escribir en un textarea. En el archivo web.xml tenemos seteado que la sesión expire cada 30min, pero hay algunos usuarios que tardan en escribir más de 30min. Como podriamos hacer para que cuando escriban por mas de ese tiempo de expiración la sesion siga disponible? Deberiamos capturar el evento de teclado?

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Estás usando jsf solamente o tienes rich faces o primefaces?, Puedes agregar un componente poll, esto envía petición periódica al servidor y evita que expire la sesión.

Answer (score 1):

En JSF uno puede usar el context de faces para especificar un tiempo de sesion maximo usando

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().setSessionMaxInactiveInterval(time);
```

Si se necesita prolongar seria por medio de un evento cada cierto tiempo por medio de una accion ajax